# Semantic segmentation mask

Tags: conv-neural-network, computer-vision, image-segmentation

What does the mask look like when doing semantic segmentation. I have 3 classes (background, liver, tumour).

Currently the input to my segmentation model looks like this

(32, 128, 128, 3) where 32 = batch_size, 128 = image width/height, 3 number of color channels -> RGB.

For labeling the masks i do the following.

1. Iterate through all the pixels of the image
2. Assign each pixel a class:

   - If the pixel belongs to the **background**, I set the RGB value at this position to **[0,0,1]**
   - If the pixel belongs to the **liver**, I set the RGB value at at this position to **[0,1,0]**
   - If the pixel belongs to the **tumour**, I set the RGB value at this position to **[1,0,0]**

which results in an image where every pixel is either (0,0,1), (0,1,0) or (1,0,0).

Is that the correct way to do it or am I completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems ok to me, the output of the network will have 3 channels, each with the probability of one of the class. (The interpretation would not be RGB anymore, just the probabilities. If you would have e.g. 5 classes, the output would have 5 channels.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!